# Configuring pidgin for IMAP

Tags: imap, pidgin

How do i configure pidgin to work with my IMAP account? (I'm using Pidgin 2.7.3 in Ubuntu 10.10) . In the Add Accounts Dialog box, the IMAP option is not listed. Please tell me which option I should choose in order to enable my IMAP account or should I insatll any plugin?

Answer (score 4):

It's not supported, as far as I can tell.  Pidgin is an instant messaging client, and IMAP is not an IM protocol (even though it does start with "IM").

Someone could theoretically write a third-party Pidgin plugin to support notification when a new mail arrives in your IMAP mailbox, but [they don't have one listed on their "plugins" page](http://developer.pidgin.im/wiki/ThirdPartyPlugins).  They've already determined that [builtin IMAP integration with Pidgin is a WONTFIX](http://developer.pidgin.im/ticket/5473).